# Probability of two consecutive heads in 20 throws

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting two consecutive heads in 20 coin tosses?

I found that the expected number of throws to get two consecutive heads is 6, implying the probability of two heads in a row is 1/6. I realize I need to use the idea from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21825/probability-over-multiple-blocks-of-events/23762#23762), which means having a $3 *3$ Transition Matrix, where:

$A$: We have not had 2 Heads in a row yet

$B$: We have not had 2 Heads in a row yet, but had one Head in the last trial

$C$: We have have 2 Heads in a row

Would this be the required transition matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}5/6 & 5/6 &0\\1/6 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1/6 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$? And then calculate $M^{20}$ and the value associated with this matrix for the entry (3,1)?

Thank You

Comment: Do you mean for A: "We have not had 2 Heads in a row yet, and the last trial was a Tail"? The way you wrote it, A includes B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three mutually exclusive states are:

1. Haven't thrown yet, or last throw was a tail. Have not had two heads yet.
2. Last throw was head. Have not had two heads yet.
3. Have had two heads in a row. This is an absorbing state.

Then the transition matrix is:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then compute $M^{20}$ as you suggested, and then

$$\mathbf{x}=M^{20}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$$

where $x_3$ is the probability that the final state is absorbing, i.e. two consecutive heads were recorded.

---

However, there is another method that reveals an exact answer that is related to the Fibonacci sequence.

Let:

- $H_n =$ prob. of getting two consecutive heads where last throw was a head, with $n$ throws left
- $T_n =$ prob. of getting two consecutive heads where last throw was a tail, with $n$ throws left

Then we have the initial (final?) conditions:

- $H_0 = 0$
- $T_0=T_1=0$

and the recursions

$$\begin{align}
H_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}T_n,\quad 0\le n\le19 \tag{1}\\[1em]
T_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}H_n+\frac{1}{2}T_n,\quad 0\le n\le19 \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

From (1) and (2):

$$T_{n+2}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}T_{n+1}+\frac{1}{4}T_{n},\quad 0\le n\le18 \tag{3}$$

From (3) it can be seen that sequence $\{T\}$ converges to $1$, so tabulate $T_n$ and $\color{blue}{1-T_n}$ against $n$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
n & T_n & 1-T_n \\
0 & 0 & 1-\frac{1}{1}\\
1 & 0 & 1-\frac{2}{2}\\
2 & \frac{1}{4} & 1-\frac{3}{4} \\
3 & \frac{3}{8} & 1-\frac{5}{8} \\
4 & \frac{1}{2} & 1-\frac{8}{16} \\
5 & \frac{19}{32} & 1-\frac{13}{32}
\end{array}$$

The numerators in the last column are Fibonacci numbers and the denominators are powers of $2$. We can conjecture that:

$$T_n = 1-\frac{F_{n+2}}{2^n} \tag{4}$$

and prove by induction. Note that $F_1=F_2=1,F_3=2$ for this Fibonacci sequence.

Clearly, by (4) we have $T_0=T_1=0$. So assuming (4) as the induction hypothesis, for $n\ge2$, we have by (3):

$$\begin{align}
T_{n+2}&=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}T_{n+1}+\frac{1}{4}T_{n} \\[1em]
       &=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{F_{n+3}}{2^{n+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{F_{n+2}}{2^{n}}\right) &(\text{by IH for }n,n+1)\\[1em]
       &=1-\frac{F_{n+3}}{2^{n+2}}-\frac{F_{n+2}}{2^{n+2}} &(\text{rearranging}) \\[1em]
       &=1-\frac{F_{n+4}}{2^{n+2}} &(\text{property of F.S.})
\end{align}$$

So this proves the IH for $n+2$ given IH for $n$ and $n+1$, hence proves the inductive step.

So we can compute the original probability as:

$$T_{20}=1-\frac{F_{22}}{2^{20}}$$

where

$$F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n$$

Then $F_{22}=17711$, so

$$\boxed{T_{20}=1-\frac{17711}{2^{20}}=1-\frac{17711}{1048576}}$$